# How to play url in iphone application?

Tags: ios4

[urlDict setObject:urlStr forKey:@"url"];

```
    [urlArray addObject:urlDict];
```

//here in urlArray i got bellow url,

http://example.com/somevidya.AVI

How to play this url in iphone application?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the url to a MPMoviePlayerController like this.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
```

then present it modally like so:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentModalViewController:video animated:YES];
```

and release the videoPlayer:

```
[videoPlayer release];
```

Comment: Thank you fro your response, But can i play .avi file in iphone application